# IPV6 not acquired from ipv6 address pool in ubuntu 12.04 for ISC server

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, ipv6

Ubuntu 14.04 running in ISC-dhcp-client is not acquiring IPV6 from the pool given in server.

Below is vim /etc/dhcp/dhcpd6.conf file

```
default-lease-time 600;
max-lease-time 7200;
subnet6 2001:0db8:0:f101::0/64{
    range6 2001:0db8:0:f101::1 2001:0db8:0:f101::254;
    range6 2001:0db8:0:f101::/64}
option dhcp6.name-servers fec0:0:0:1::1;
option dhcp6.domain-search "domain.example";
```

Below is the error when I run dhclient restart

> can't set SO_REUSEPORT option on dhcp socket: Protocol not available

Comment: Did you disable IPv6 on the client machine?

Comment: No I haven't done that. I was trying to setup a local network of my own. Client was acquiring IPV6 (Link Local) when connected to outside network and my own network. But from the address pool staring with 2001::0, which i gave in my server settings, the client was not reflecting that address.

Comment: Please do not use site-local unicast addresses (`fec0::/10`), they have been deprecated for ten years.

Answer (score 1):

Seemly it's a bug when isc dhcpv6 server runs on Linux with kernel < 3.9.

https://lists.isc.org/pipermail/dhcp-users/2014-March/017717.html